# How to disable particular dates in datepicker's calender

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need to disable multiple dates in single month of `JQuery- Bootstrap  Datepicker` .
As i tried with multiple answers here over SO and else also. But my problem didn't resolved. 
As I'm having list of dates i need to disable over datepicker. But, datepicker isn't responding with date disability.

I used to work over JQuery and boostrap to view Datepicker. Used CDN to load script. 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<div class="input-group date">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
<input value="" readonly="" class="form-control" name="doi" id="doi" type="text">
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var array = ["09/14/2019","09/15/2019","09/16/2019"];

$('#doi').datepicker({
 beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    },
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],   //Disable sunday
    autoclose:true,
})  ;
  </script>
```

After executing this script i'm receiving an error related to `.formDate()` 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined`  
[image: formDate function]

But After adding: `<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" ></script>` 
 after JQuery CDN, this error was resolved but Disabling date is still not working.

Expected: `Disable` : `09/14/2019`,`09/15/2019`,`09/16/2019` from datepicker.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap add `bootstrap-datepicker.min.js` and `bootstrap-datepicker.css` and try

Comment: @NijinKoderi Thanks.. But still repeating same error of.  `(index):10996 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined`

Comment: @nithin `jQuery.datepicker.formatDate()` is not available for `bootstrap`, it is for `jQuery` datepicker

Comment: @nithin try my new solution. first solution for `Jquery Datepicker` and second solution is for `bootstrap Datepicker`

Answer (score 5):

you need to add `jquery-ui.min.js` and `jquery-ui.css`

```js
var array = ["2019-09-14","2019-09-15","2019-09-16"]

$('#doi').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input id="doi" />
```

Comment: @nithin_kumar happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)

Comment: @Ninjin Koderi Thanks for your response. But this also not working. As i'm using `bootstrap-datepicker.min.js` for styling and other features also. After Including all your cdn and scripting stuff  my datepicker becomes constant (neither putting any error nor disabling date).

Comment: Then why did you put above as `jquery datepicker`??

Comment: because i'm using : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That is for `jQuery` right? not for the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution for `Bootstrap Datepicker`. dont be confuse with both. from `jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date)` its clear that you are trying to use `Jquery Datepicker`.

```js
var datesForDisable = ["2019-09-14","2019-09-15","2019-09-16"]

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            weekStart: 1,
            calendarWeeks: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            beforeShowDay: function (currentDate) {
                var dayNr = currentDate.getDay();
                var dateNr = moment(currentDate.getDate()).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
                if (datesForDisable.length > 0) {
                     for (var i = 0; i < datesForDisable.length; i++) {                        
                       if (moment(currentDate).unix()==moment(datesForDisable[i],'YYYY-MM-DD').unix()){
                                return false;
                           }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker">
```

Comment: thanks for your support buddy.!! :) I Got my expected result.

Comment: ha ha ! happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)

Comment: sure i'll. Because of low reputation. I cant mark right now.

Answer (score 0):

After working & Searching alot for this question i'll get my answer.
Using JQuery CDN: 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
var datearray = ["09/14/2019","09/15/2019","09/16/2019"];
$('#doi').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',       
    datesDisabled: datearray,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],   //Disable sunday
    autoclose:true,
    todayHighlight: true,
});
```

Here, `datesDisabled:` plays vital role for me. 
Thanks for all your suggestions & response.